# Making Rest call within a rest call angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am trying to make a REST call to get the total count of the cities based on the text entered in a textbox.
I am making the same REST call the second time to get 25 records for the same search text.
For example if I entered the text Paris, the 1st rest call will take the maxPage size to 1000 and get me all the records.
And the second time, the maxPage is set to 25 to get the first 25 records.

The idea is to show the total number of records matching the search text and also show the 1st 25 records.
(for ex: 25/400)

**The problem** that I am facing is by the time I am done with entering the text, the 1st rest call is taking only a part of the text and the 2nd call is taking the whole text.
The count returned for the text is not matching the 2nd call's response.

For example: the 1st call is ending up with the text 'Par' and getting me 250 results where as the 2nd call is taking 'Paris'. I am ending up with 25/250 which is not correct.
May be this is because of some timing issue since the searchCities is called on ng-change. I cannot introduce a button on the screen so it has to be ng-change only.
Please help me resolve this.

Please have a look at the below code.

```
$scope.getCityCount = function(phrase){
var searchPhrase = phrase;
var dataObj =  { term: searchPhrase, maxPage: 1000, pagefrom: 0 };
var srchdata = JSON.stringify( dataObj );
Cities.query( {}, srchdata, function(cityData) { //1st REST call
    if (cityData.status == "success") {
        $scope.cityCount= cityData.data.length; //total records

        $scope.loadMoreCities(searchPhrase); //2nd call:to get 25 records
    }
});
}

$scope.loadMoreCities = function(phrase){
    var searchParam = { term: phrase, maxPage: 25, pagefrom: 0 };
    Cities.query( {}, searchParam, function(dataObj) {
        if (dataObj.status == "success") {
            var citiesFound = dataObj.data;
        }
    });
}

$scope.searchCities = function( phrase ) {
    if(phrase.length > 1){
        $scope.getCityCount(phrase);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Though I am searching for Paris, I am getting final result for Pa. Please see the logs::

```
getSearchCount#1: {"searchTerm":"Paris","maxPage":10000,"pagefrom":0}is=====400
 getSearchCount#2: {"searchTerm":"Paris","maxPage":25,"pagefrom":0}is===== 25
 getSearchCount#1: {"searchTerm":"Pari","maxPage":10000,"pagefrom":0}is===== 105
 getSearchCount#2: {"searchTerm":"Pari","maxPage":25,"pagefrom":0}is===== 25
 getSearchCount#1: {"searchTerm":"Pa","maxPage":10000,"pagefrom":0}is===== 722
 getSearchCount#2: {"searchTerm":"Pa","maxPage":25,"pagefrom":0}is===== 25
```

On the screen I get 25/722

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phrase" ng-change="searchCities(phrase)">
```

Comment: definitely a timing issue. Sounds like you need to somehow throttle this and possibly send the requests in parallel (or reduce down to a single request.) for example, why do you need to count the cities, if you're also requesting them? you can get the array len of the cities to get the count and return that with the get cities request.

Comment: The first time the page loads, the cities data has like 1000+ records, so we get only 25 records and if the user wants to see more, there is a 'more' button on the bottom of the page which keeps adding 25 more records to the list. This is nothing but pagination. The count comes into picture only when the user searches for some text.

Comment: You should not make two separate request. You need to embbed your total number of records as part of loadMoreCities response. With your current code issue is you are calling loadMoreCities with term:$scope.phrase. Try calling loadMoreCities with current srchdata.

Comment: @amighty: How can I make a single call ? Please advise.

Comment: On server side when you return response for loadMoreCities. Just embed your total cityCount for give phrase to the same response dataObj and use it to set $scope.cityCount = dataObj.totalcount.

Comment: @amighty: Server side implementation is done using elastic search and the solution that you are giving does not sound flexible enough. Is there a client-side only solution to this ?

Comment: Ok...so if you do not have control over server side then just try modifying loadMoreCities to recieve current phrase argument and call it loadMoreCities (srchdata) from getCityCount and use that argument as term

Comment: @amighty: I made the edit per your suggestion. I see that the second call is taking the same searchTerm as the 1st call. I still dont get the desired result. Please see the logs in my edit.

Comment: you can make use of $timeout or easy one is put ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" in input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty bad idea. You should do server side paging instead. Have the API return the pager object along with the search results. For example, here is an API GET request:

> /api/accounts?searchText=someText&pageSize=25&page=1

Here is the response:

```
{
  "pager": {
    "pageCount": 1,
    "totalItemCount": 342,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "pageSize": 25,
    "hasPreviousPage": false,
    "hasNextPage": true,
    "isFirstPage": true,
    "isLastPage": false,
    "firstItemOnPage": 1,
    "lastItemOnPage": 25
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 15343,
      "name": "Account Name",
    },
    // more accounts returned here...
    {
      "id": 2314,
      "name": "Account Name 2",
    }
  ],
  "searchText": "someText"
}
```

When the client wants to load more, the request would change to this:

> /api/accounts?searchText=someText&pageSize=25&page=2

..where you see we're trying to fetch the 2nd page.

How you implement server side paging is another question. Here is a rudimentary server [side paging example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-with-Web-API-43e5de16) to give you an idea.

**Update:**

---

If you absolutely can't change the api to deliver paging information, try using a debounce delay. You can read about it in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) but it will essentially trigger the ng-change update when the timer expires instead of on the keypress. Here is how you would implement it.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phrase" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }' ng-change="searchCities(phrase)">
```

Comment: I wish the server side was implemented this way.

Comment: If you have no control over the server side, you should chain the requests so inside searchCities you would say $scope.getCitiesCount(dataObj).then(function(){ //success callback, call loadMoreCities here }, function(){ //error callback });

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing still not getting the expected result. Timing problem. Not sure how to make the call synchronous.

Comment: If you have no control over the api, try using debounce. I updated my answer to include that option. That may help but I bet you will still have some timing related issues. This is more of a hack. I would change the api or argue introducing a button to search on click. Both would be better solutions.

Comment: debounce option is neat. Works for my use case. Thanks !